# javafx find the right path

Tags: java, path, javafx

I get following structure:

> ```
> project
> |---+build
> |---+dist
> |---+nbproject
> |----src
> |-------client
> |----------stuff
> |-------------controller
> |----------------DefaultController.java
> |-------------files
> |-------------fxml
> |----------------DefaultFXML.fxml
> |-------------img
> |-------------lib
> |---------------ContentManager.java
> |-------------root
> |---------------StartClass.Java
> |---+build.xml
> |---manifest.mf
> ```

I'm setting in the ContentManager the fxml-Files like:

```
public static final String 
        DEFAULT_SCREEN_FXML = "../fxml/Default.fxml";
```

But i get allways a nullPointerException. And i dont want to work with absolute Path. So how to finde out the relative path? 
And is it right to set the controller of the fxml-file with:

```
fx:id="client.stuff.controller.DefaultController"
```

??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you deploy your application, you typically create a jar file which includes the class files and all the resources. You need to load the fxml file from inside the jar file, i.e. as a resource. In this context, the path element ".." doesn't really mean anything.

Use

```
public static final String 
        DEFAULT_SCREEN_FXML = "/client/stuff/fxml/Default.fxml";
```

(the path is relative to the classpath).

and of course load it with

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(DEFAULT_SCREEN_FXML));
```

or something similar.

Answer (score 3):

> is it right to set the controller of the fxml-file with...`fx:id`...?

No, this is totally wrong.  You should set the controller using `fx:controller`, not `fx:id`.

`fx:id` is for mapping `@FXML` elements in controllers to elements defined in an FXML document, it is not for mapping the controller class itself.

Refer to the [Introduction to FXML](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html) document for more information.

So, don't use:

```
fx:id="client.stuff.controller.DefaultController"
```

Instead use:

```
fx:controller="client.stuff.controller.DefaultController"
```

---

James's answer for the other part of your question to do with path resolution is correct.

Comment: ah sorry, you're right. I mean fx:controller! But Thank you :)