# Display Image in JavaFX using fxml

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have been unsuccessfully trying to display my image in my JavaFX application using fxml.
My code:

```java
...
<ImageView fitHeight="24" fitWidth="24"
    pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
        <Image url="@res/icon.png"/>
</ImageView>
...
```

My project directory structure:
[image]

There is no error, but my image is not displaying. I think the image was loaded, but not displayed.
Is this possible? How can I check? If it is, shouldn't there be an error for it?

Infact, even if I give an incorrect name, there is no runtime error. So maybe not loaded?

I have also tried loading different images and changing the dimensions, nothing works.

---

I have tried:

1. `"/res/icon.png"` -> Runtime error #1
2. `"res/icon.png"` -> Lint error + Runtime error #1
3. `"/../res/icon.png"` -> Lint error + Runtime error #1
4. `"../res/icon.png"` -> Lint error + Runtime error #1
5. `"@/res/icon.png"` -> Runtime error #2
6. `"@res/icon.png"` -> Lint error (What I am using)
7. `"@/../res/icon.png"` -> Lint error + Runtime error #2
8. `"@../res/icon.png"` -> Lint error, no display

Runtime Error #1: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found`

Runtime Error #2: `Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Invalid resource: /res/icon.png not found on the classpath`

(I know we shouldn't use .. or . in urls. I was just testing)

---

I have seen:

1. [Why does Image don't load in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62196807/why-does-image-dont-load-in-javafx) which is exactly my configuration.
2. [How to show image using ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22710053/how-can-i-show-an-image-using-the-imageview-component-in-javafx-and-fxml) from where I got the proper way to link images in fxml. No error, but image not loading/displaying.
3. [ImageView does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22635021/javafx-imageview-via-fxml-does-not-work) but I would like to do this in fxml *only*.
4. [Can't load JavaFX Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53952266/cant-load-javafx-image) again fxml only.
5. [Cannot load Image in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16099427/cannot-load-image-in-javafx) again fxml only.
6. [Load Image to ImageView JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22744283/load-image-to-imageview-javafx) again fxml only.
7. [JavaFX Image loading error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28724478/javafx-image-loading-error) I am not using CSS.
8. [JavaFX image loading in background and threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31172090/javafx-image-loading-in-background-and-threads) not what I'm interested in.
9. [How to determine correct path...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61531317/how-do-i-determine-the-correct-path-for-fxml-files-css-files-images-and-other) very extensive, but what about fxml?

---

Edit: I recreated a duplicate of the original project and tried the troubleshooting following the comments.

The results (response to troubleshooting section):

1. ***Proper image name***: The name was valid, and the image properly deployed to `out` folder. But it was not recognized by the IDE and resulted in error or no display.
2. ***Proper paths***

   a) *Absolute URLs*

Interestingly, the `getClass().getResource("/res/icon.png").getExternalForm()` method gives:

```
 file:/C:/Users/Chander%20Shekhar/IdeaProjects/TestRes/out/production/TestRes/res/icon.png
```

and works. Not sure if the `file:` should be there. The `getPath()` method gives:

```
/C:/Users/Chander%20Shekhar/IdeaProjects/TestRes/out/production/TestRes/res/icon.png
```

and doesn't work (Runtime error#1). Removing the first `/` gave another error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: unknown protocol: c
```

b) *Relative URLs*

So I actually made a marker class in my `res` folder, and used `ImageMarker.class.getResource("icon.png").toExternalForm()` which gave

```
file:/C:/Users/Chander%20Shekhar/IdeaProjects/TestRes/out/production/TestRes/res/icon.png
```

Same as the first example, and works!

3. ***Classpath***: I also made sure I had the relative address from project root, the `src` folder (which I believe is the classpath root. [Wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23188511/javafx-find-the-right-path)?)

But in the end, all of this is *still* irrelevant, since I am using fxml. God!

Comment: Where is your fxml file located?

Comment: @AllanJuan my fxmls are in the `View` folder. Okay, I'll put them in the resources. Wow, it worked! :O Thanks!

Comment: You have a solution, but I would check here whether or not the image file is being deployed, see “Troubleshooting” in the link you have in 9.

Comment: @James_D I read it, but I'll reread it. I was confused by the fact that there was no error, and yet no image displayed. And when I changed the name to something invalid, again no error. Why does one path give error, and one does not, even when image is not loaded?

Comment: @JaideepShekhar I can’t give a complete answer to that, but note some errors are immediately detectable, and some aren’t. E.g. if the URL is simply not valid (malformed), the `FXMLLoader` can’t create a `URL` object and an exception can be thrown. OTOH there are certainly cases where that can’t be done - imagine you were using a `http:` url which didn’t exist, and background loading the image. The error wouldn’t happen immediately, so no exception could be thrown - the image’s `error` flag would just be set to `true`. Your cases are less clear, but exceptions aren’t always thrown for bad urls.

Comment: @JaideepShekhar For troubleshooting, I was just suggesting you needed to check the *build* folder, not the *source* folder, to make sure the image was actually being deployed (and to check where it was being deployed to). From the solution below, it seems pretty clear the issue was the IDE not deploying the `res` folder.

Comment: @James_D please see the edits in response to the troubleshooting.

Comment: Also, is using `<Image url="@../images/icon.png" />` in the fxml okay? As opposed to in the java code? Project directory structure as @Allan has described.

Comment: Yes, if something can be done both in Java code or in FXML, it's up to you where you're going to do it. My only advice is to be consistent with whatever you choose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you to use a resources folder, and put both your FXML and images in that folder. So you'd have this file structure:

```
src/
|-- main/
    | -- java/
    | -- resources/
         | -- fxml/screen.fxml
         | -- img/image.png
```

Then on `screen.fxml` you would do something like

```xml
<ImageView pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
    <image>
        <Image url="@../img/image.png" />
    </image>
</ImageView>
```

That's how I organize my projects and it works just fine. CSS files will live in resources too, hope that helps.

PS: You have a `res/` folder, but Java won't recognize it as a resource folder unless you acknowledge it. If you're on IntelliJ, you can right click it and then choose "Mark as resources root". If you use maven there are ways to declare it as your resource folder. Anyways, if you just rename it to `resources/` it will be automatically considered as your resource folder.

Comment: Wow! This worked. XD Btw, there is no option to "mark as resources root" for me. I simply renamed it to `resources`. Is that enough? How can I check?

Comment: Don't worry, if you renamed it to resources it should be enough ;)

Comment: I will accept this answer tomorrow (because apparently you should wait a day to let other people answer ;-))